# How to pass variables for Terraform S3 Backend resource?

Tags: terraform

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
    key    = "path/to/my/key"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to provide values for bucket and key above through variables file?

Because when I try doing the same like this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = var.bucket
    key    = var.key
  }
}
```

, I get the following error:

```
Error: Variables not allowed

on main.tf line 3, in terraform:
3:      bucket = var.bucket

Variables may not be used here.

Error: Variables not allowed

on main.tf line 4, in terraform:
4:      key = key

Variables may not be used here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we can't pass run-time values for backend bucket and key for storing state files.

This is where the concept of `Terraform Workspaces` comes in!!

Comment: beware, if it's for separating environments, workspaces is not suitable for this, as stated in the docs https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces

Answer (score 12):

Create a file named `backend.tfvars` with content:

```
bucket = "mybucket"
key    = "path/to/my/key"
```

Specify this file name in a command line option to the `terraform init` command:

```
terraform init -backend-config=backend.tfvars
```

You need a separate backend config file instead of your usual tfvars file because these values are used when you set up your backend. That means they need to be provided when you run `terraform init`, not later when you use the backend with commands like `terraform apply`.

See the terraform documentation on [partial configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html#partial-configuration) for more details.

Comment: Thanks much! Can't we pass the bucket and key names for backend through `variables.tf` or `.tfvars` file? Reason I ask is - we have dozens of applications and half a dozen environment for each application. So totally we need almost 100 state files. Using 100 environment variables -is that a good practice? Please advise.

Comment: When I gave backend bucket name and key in .tfvars, I got the error as I explained in my question. Am not sure I understood the solution. So in addition to giving the backend bucket name and key in tfvars, I should also create an TF_CLI_ARGS_init environment variable? Please help!

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to read the backend configuration from a file.

Comment: I believe this answer has become dated and is now incorrect. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration
> A backend block cannot refer to named values (like input variables, locals, or data source attributes).

Comment: Did Terraform change Partial Configuration? The current [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration#partial-configuration) says _A configuration file may be specified via the `init` command line. To specify a file, use the `-backend-config=PATH` option when running `terraform init`_.

Comment: +1 to having a common tfvars file. If I have separate tfvars file for backend-config I risk overwriting the state when I terraform apply with a tfvars belonging to some other environment. Is there no way we can use just one tfvars?